# How to call to another services in Symfony?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I got a problem like this
I got a service to inject doctrine and use the entity manager to insert a user record into database: UsersService.php

And i got a service to send email: MyEmailService.php

All both services injected in the services.yml(follow this docs http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html). All of them work fine.

So now my problem is: I have a class call UserFacade.php(**not extends any controller**). It has a method "addUser". In this function it will call to UserService.php to insert a record into database, then call the MyEmailService.php to send an email to user's email.
How can i do that in Symphony? I'm the newbie with bundle in Symphony.

Please help
Thanks

Comment: have you tried including the class itself to a controller?

Comment: Yes @MikeAnte. My problem is how can i call to doctrine manager from UserService? And then call the UserService from UserFacade

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to [declare your dependencies in the constructor](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/types.html#constructor-injection) of the UserFacade class. This is one way to allow symfony to inject the dependencies:

```php
class UserFacade 
{
    /** @var UserService */
    private $userService;

    /** @var EmailService */
    private $emailService;

    public function __construct(UserService $userService, MyEmailService $emailService) 
    {
        $this->userService = $userService;
        $this->emailService = $emailService;
    }

    public function addUser(User $user) 
    {
        $this->userService->add($user);
        $this->emailService->sendUserMail($user, ...);
    }
}
```

Then you have to declare the dependencies in your service.yml (assuming your using YAML, XML is quite similar):

```yaml
services:
    user_service:
        class:     UserService
        ...
    email_service: 
        class:     EmailService
        ...
    user_facade:
        class:     UserFacade
        arguments: [@user_service, @email_service]
```

And then use the facade in your controller:

```php
class UserController 
{
    public function addUserAction(Request $request) 
    {
        // Do stuff with Request to populate the $user object
        $this->get('user_facade')->addUser($user);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to register your UserFacade class as a service, inject into it UserService (and MyEmailService). Then call UserService and MyEmailService from UserFacade service as a property:

```
$this->userService-><methid>
// and so on
```